# Remove focus ring from view in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm making a macOS app with SwiftUI, in which I want to use the arrow keys to offset a `Circle` view. The only problem I have is that my `Circle` view is surrounded by a blue focus ring, which I would like to remove, but don't know how. Other than that, my code works fine. (see the image below, I'd like to remove the blue border)

[image: The blue border around the circle isn't supposed to be there.]

I've found many questions on Stack Overflow about removing the focus ring from a `TextField`, but not for other types of views. How do I remove the focus ring from an non-`TextField` view using SwiftUI? If it isn't possible to do so, how else can I achieve the same functionality without the focus ring?

Code:

```
struct UITestbed: View {

    @State private var xInput: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var yInput: CGFloat = 0

    var body: some View {

        Circle()
            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
            .focusable()
            .offset(x: self.xInput, y: self.yInput)
            .onMoveCommand { (direction) in
                withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                    switch direction {
                    case .right:
                        self.xInput += 10
                    case .left:
                        self.xInput -= 10
                    case .up:
                        self.yInput -= 10
                    case .down:
                        self.yInput += 10
                    default:
                        fatalError("Unknown move command")
                    }
                }}

    }

}
```

Comment: When I try to reproduce your code, I do not get a focus ring but can not move it with the keys either

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61802318/swiftui-onmovecommand-actions-arent-executed) make it movable with keys?

Comment: @qitanshi Just found it, yes that should do it. Thanks